# How do you create a Jekyll site?

Tags: yaml, jekyll

Please tell me how to create a basic Jekyll site.  I am especially confused about the file _config.yml and the YAML front matter.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. YAML is simply a means of encoding simple data structures in a text file. Jekyll uses it for configuration; what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't quite understand the wording of you questions, but I'll take a shot. I'm guessing you are referring to one of two things. Either the config file or the YAML front matter. Whichever one, see below for a basic primer to get a jekyll site up and running. It shows the usage of both in context.

In an empty directory, create the following:

1. A new directory named `_layouts`.
2. A new directory named `_posts`.
3. A new directory named `_site`.
4. A file named `index.md` with the following content:

   ```
   ---
   layout: default
   ---

   # My Jekyll site

   Welcome to my Jekyll site
   ```

   (Note: the "layout: default" surrounded by the two lines of dashes is the YAML Front Matter. Specifying "default" means that jekyll will use the "default.html" file in the _layouts directory listed below.)
5. A file named `_config.yml` with the following default content:

   ```
   safe:        false
   auto:        false
   server:      false
   server_port: 4000
   base-url:    /

   source:      .
   destination: ./_site
   plugins:     ./_plugins

   future:      true
   lsi:         false
   pygments:    false
   markdown:    maruku
   permalink:   date

   maruku:
     use_tex:    false
     use_divs:   false
     png_engine: blahtex
     png_dir:    images/latex
     png_url:    /images/latex

   rdiscount:
     extensions: []

   kramdown:
     auto_ids: true,
     footnote_nr: 1
     entity_output: as_char
     toc_levels: 1..6
     use_coderay: false

     coderay:
       coderay_wrap: div
       coderay_line_numbers: inline
       coderay_line_numbers_start: 1
       coderay_tab_width: 4
       coderay_bold_every: 10
       coderay_css: style
   ```

---

There are two more files you'll want to create for the example,

1. Inside the "_layouts" directory, a file named `default.html` with the following:

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <title>My Jekyll Site</title>
   </head>
   <body>

       <!-- This will be replaced with your content -->
       {{ content }}


   </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. Inside the "_posts" directory, a file named `2011-07-29-my-first-jekyll-post.md` with the following:

   ```
   ---
   layout: default
   ---

   # My First Jekyll Post

   The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
   ```

   (Note: Once again, the "layout: default" surrounded by the two lines of dashes is the YAML Front Matter and specifies that "default.html" will be used for the template.)

---

At this point the directory structure should look like this:

```
./_config.yml
./_layouts
./_posts
./_posts/2011-07-29-my-first-jekyll-post.md
./_site
./index.md
```

Once all that is setup, from the command line go to the directory that has the index.md file in it and run `jekyll`. You should see a quick report like:

```
Configuration from /some-path/_config.yml
Building site: . -> ./_site
Successfully generated site: . -> ./_site
```

Two output file will have been created:

- ./_site/index.html
- ./_site/2011/07/29/my-first-jekyll-post.html

Those files correspond to the two markdown files after the were transformed to HTML and dropped into the default.html wrapper replacing the "{{ content }}" string.

That should get your started with the basics.

Comment: The config.yml must be named with an initial underscore: `_config.yml`. To test the server, you can use `jekyll --server`

Comment: Thanks, @FèlixGalindoAllué - I've corrected the typo where I missed the underscore.

Comment: You are a star.